# Replace values from one existing dataset with values from another existing dataset

Tags: sas

I have dataset1 that I want to replace the current values for variableX with the values for that same variable from dataset2. I want the rest of dataset1 to remain the same.

How do I do this?

Also, dataset1 has 89 observations and dataset2 has 9098 observations. I only need the first 89 observations from dataset2.

thank you

I tried the following

```
libname data '\\filepath\dataset1folder';
libname data2 '\\filepath\dataset2folder';

data data.dataset1;
    set data2.dataset2;
    CWEIGHT = CWEIGHT;
RUN;
```

Comment: How do you know that the first 89 observations in the second dataset are related in any way to the first 89 observations in the first dataset?  Normally you should have some type of ID variable that would allow you know that you are writing the new variable's values into the right record.

Comment: Does the second dataset have more than 89 observations? If so then how do you know that you only want the first 89 observations?  Normally there would be some variable you could test that would indicate which observations you wanted to use from a dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements:

- Replace the current values in dataset1 for variableX with the values for that same variable from dataset2. I want the rest of dataset1 to remain the same.
- I only need the first 89 observations from dataset2.

You need to obtain the first 89 observations from dataset2 and only variableX. This can be achieved using `KEEP=` and `OBS=`:

```
set data2.dataset2 (KEEP=variableX OBS=89);
```

And you want to update dataset1 using this data, so you need to use a datastep that will read and write dataset1, while also incorporating the above:

```
libname data '\\filepath\dataset1folder';
libname data2 '\\filepath\dataset2folder';

data data.dataset1;
    /* The data step is a loop - this statement loads the first row of dataset1 */
    set data.dataset1;
    /* This loads the first row of dataset2, but only variableX - if variableX is present in dataset1 then it is overwritten */
    set data2.dataset2 (KEEP=variableX OBS=89);
RUN;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `merge` statement and `in=` dataset option.

```
data want;
  merge data.dataset1(in=_in1_) data2.dataset2(keep=variableX);
  if _in1_=1;
run;
```

Image the datasets are boxes, the `merge` statement just places these boxes next to each other horizontally and aligns their tops. If there are same name variables in different datasets, the former one will be rewrite by the following one.
Following a dataset, the `in=` option  create a 0-1 variable, `_in1_` in this example, to indicate if one observation comes from this dataset or not. Since you only want to observations from `dataset1`, you can use `if _in1_=1` to subset the result of merging.